# Bypass cloudflare captcha in Wordpress for Json API

Tags: php, wordpress, cloudflare

I am developing a API service for Wordpress website but cloudflare captcha creating problem in this because it is on the entrance of website to prevent from spamming.

Answer (score 1):

is the API being accessed by something on the frontend (i.e. Javascript) or instead by a backend service?

If it's being accessed by a backend service, you can simply [whitelist the server IP in the Cloudflare dashboard](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217074967-How-do-I-control-access-to-my-site-). To do this, go to the Firewall app and click Access Rules. You'll see this under IP Firewall:

[image: Cloudflare IP Firewall]

You can then enter the IP and select the whitelist option.